# Mysql: Display query results not containing text patterns from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to display query result only if a text pattern from a table does not appears in the product name.

```
+-----------------------------------------+          +--------+
|             Product Name                |          |pattern |
+-----------------------------------------+          +--------+
|Gangster Barbie with guns & accessories  |          |  Gun   |
|Very Safe Playdoh                        |          |  Drug  |          
|Star Wars Lego                           |          |  nam   |
|Transformers Decepticon Druglord         |          |        |
|GTA: Namcat Version                      |          |        |
+-----------------------------------------+          +--------+
```

Would like to have result:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|             Product Name                |
+-----------------------------------------+
|Very Safe Playdoh                        |
|Star Wars Lego                           |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I've tried LIKE or INSTR such as:

```
select `Product_Name` 
from Product_table 
where NOT LIKE '%'+(select `text_pattern`.`Keywords` from `text_pattern`)+'%';
```

but none seems to work properly. Could someone please help or point in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method using `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from product p
where not exists (select 1
                  from patterns pat
                  where p.name like concat('%', pat.pattern, '%')
                 );
```

Note:  MySQL does not use `+` for string concatenation.  It uses the `concat()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
E.g.

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;

CREATE TABLE product
(name                VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO product VALUES
('Gangster Barbie with guns & accessories'),
('Very Safe Playdoh'),
('Star Wars Lego'),
('Transformers Decepticon Druglord'),
('GTA: Namcat Version');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS patterns;

CREATE TABLE patterns
(pattern VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO patterns VALUES
('Gun'),('Drug'),('nam');

SELECT * FROM product a LEFT JOIN patterns b ON a.name LIKE CONCAT('%',b.pattern,'%');
+-----------------------------------------+---------+
| name                                    | pattern |
+-----------------------------------------+---------+
| Gangster Barbie with guns & accessories | Gun     |
| GTA: Namcat Version                     | nam     |
| Star Wars Lego                          | NULL    |
| Transformers Decepticon Druglord        | Drug    |
| Very Safe Playdoh                       | NULL    |
+-----------------------------------------+---------+
```